# Sharepoint column formatting carried over in all views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have SharePoint list with multiple views (in modern experience) and when I format a column in one view, the same formatting is applied to the column on all other views.

How do I break this and have the formatting only apply to one view?

Comment: Old thread but related question: If, as @theChrisKent stated, "Column formatting is applied regardless of what view it's used in...", is there a way for JSON list view formatting in the All Items view be carried over into subsequent views? I don't see a way to create a new view based on an existing view like in SP2013. Thanks-
Charlie

Comment: Did you try from classic experience list settings page?

Comment: This does not answer original question. As this is a new question, you have to use [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) option to create a new question. You can mention the link of this post in your question as this provides context for your question.

Comment: @GaneshSanap You're right. I'm sorry about that. I'll create a new question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Column formatting is applied regardless of what view it's used in. It isn't possible to target a specific view with column formatting. You can, however, do this with view formatting. That may or may not meet your needs, though.

If you have more details about what you're trying to accomplish, there may be other options.

Comment: Well, in one view I want a date to be red if it's in the past and in another I want don't want it red and in one view I want the Title to be bigger but not in the other views... I guess I could create calculated columns for this and get away with it

Comment: You can change the UI of complete row using `additionalRowClass` (view formatting) based on date value. But (as I said in my answer above) you cannot have different JSON (column) formatting for single column in different views.

Comment: Thanks... I will use the info provided. I should be able to get something my users will be happy with.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, when you apply JSON formatting to column, it will be applied at column level.

So, you cannot break it and have different formatting in different views.

Comment: As @theChrisKent said, you can format your list view altogether using [view formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting). And you can have different formatting for different views. But it will take more efforts and that may not meet your requirements.