# SharePoint Online List View JSON Formatting Not Carrying Over to New Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

As an offshoot of a comment from @theChrisKent [Column Formatting Not Carrying Over](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285877/sharepoint-column-formatting-carried-over-in-all-views), if as he stated, "Column formatting is applied regardless of what view it's used in...", is there a way (*in a Modern List, not Classic*) for my JSON list view formatting in the All Items view to be carried over into subsequent views?

Maybe I assumed incorrectly that creating a new Modern List View *COULD* be created based on the column order and formatting of the original view, as in SP2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a new list view based on existing list view in modern SharePoint list.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Change the width of any column in list view slightly like:

   [image]
3. Once you make this small change, you will the `*` added next to view name (Say "All Items).
4. Click on View dropdown (where "All Items" is shown) and select "Save view as" option
5. On "Save as" popup, give different/new name to list view and click "Save"

   [image]
6. This will create a new list with same JSON formatting (column as well as view formatting):

   [image]

Comment: Wow, Ganesh! That is brilliant. Thank you very much!
Cheers!!